# NotifyIcon BalloonTipClicked Event not Firing

Tags: c#, events, delegates, notifyicon

Hi I'm trying to run some code when a user clicks on a balloon tip. At the moment it's showing the balloon tip but when I click on it the delegate is not being fired.

This is where the NotifyIcon is created

```
    private NotifyIcon notifyIcon;

    public ClockOutTimer(DateTime? clockOutTime)
    {
        //IF CLOCK OUT TIME = NULL SET CLOCK OUT TIME TO 5 HOURS IN FUTURE
        ClockOutTime = clockOutTime ?? DateTime.Now.AddHours(5);
        notifyIcon = new NotifyIcon()
            {
                Icon = Properties.Resources.MainIcon,
                Text = "Organiser"
            };

        //CREATE DELEGATE FOR BALOON CLICKED
        notifyIcon.BalloonTipClicked += delegate
        {
            //NOT GOING HERE :(
            MessageBox.Show("TEST");
        };
        notifyIcon.BalloonTipIcon = ToolTipIcon.None;
        notifyIcon.BalloonTipText = String.Format("It is nearing {0} would you like to clock out?", ClockOutTime.ToString("HH:mm"));
        notifyIcon.BalloonTipTitle = "Organiser";

        //START REMINDER THREAD
        _Reminder = new Thread(new ThreadStart(_reminder));
        _Reminder.Start();
    }
```

This is where the balloon tip is being called

```
        private void Remind()
    {
        //IF USER IS IN REMIND USER TO CLOCK OUT
        if (!Global.CurrentUser.In)
        { this.Dispose(); return; }
        notifyIcon.Visible = true;
        notifyIcon.ShowBalloonTip(20000);
        //Thread.Sleep(5000);
        //notifyIcon.Visible = false;
        //this.Dispose();
    }
```

Also tried it with the method that IntelliSense creates for you but that didn't work either.

---

Changed to

```
            NotifyIcon notifyIcon = new NotifyIcon()
        {
            Icon = Properties.Resources.MainIcon,
            Text = "Organiser",
            BalloonTipIcon = ToolTipIcon.None,
            BalloonTipText = String.Format("It is nearing {0} would you like to clock out?", ClockOutTime.ToString("HH:mm")),
            BalloonTipTitle = "Organiser",
        };

        notifyIcon.BalloonTipClosed += new EventHandler(BalloonClicked);
        notifyIcon.Click += new EventHandler(BalloonClicked);
        notifyIcon.BalloonTipClicked += new EventHandler(BalloonClicked);
        notifyIcon.BalloonTipShown += new EventHandler(BalloonClicked);
        notifyIcon.Disposed += new EventHandler(BalloonClicked);
        notifyIcon.MouseClick += (object sender, MouseEventArgs e) => MessageBox.Show(e.X.ToString());
        notifyIcon.Visible = true;
        notifyIcon.ShowBalloonTip(20000);
```

Now all of the code is in one method but it's still not working. None of the events fire

---

UPDATED

This was due to me not running the method off the main thread. Thanks for your help

Comment: Hmm, it's strange it compiles  as your delegate is not an EventHandler, change it to notifyIcon.BalloonTipClicked += (sender, e) => MessageBox.Show("TEST");

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try replacing the following:

```
notifyIcon.BalloonTipClicked += delegate
    {
        //NOT GOING HERE :(
        MessageBox.Show("TEST");
    };
```

with:

```
notifyIcon.BalloonTipClicked += (sender, e) => {
    //Your code.
};
```

Comment: Fixed now thanks, it was due to not running the method on the same thread where Application.Run() was called.